# jquery autocomplete filtering

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I have a page, which uses jQuery Autocomplete on the second two textboxes (investigator and institution). It is getting the data fine, and displaying it, but for some reason it is not filtering the list of data as i continue to type.

Anyone know why? Is there something i need to do to turn this on? According to the [jQuery site](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/), the only options to the autocomplete initializer are **delay**, **minLength** and **source**.

Thanks in advance! I'm using jQ v1.4.1 and jQui v.1.8rc1.

Below is the code which I am calling on $(document).ready().

```
function hookUpAutoCompletes() {
    $('table#params input[name=sinvestigator]').autocomplete({
        source: "json-investigators.asp", 
        minLength: 2
    })

    $('table#params input[name=sinstitution]').autocomplete({
        source: "json-institutions.asp",
        minLength: 2
    })
}
```

Comment: i haven't used jQ-UI. i didn't know the autocomplete was out yet. i use JZ's jquery-autocomplete plugin.

but i tried out your test page. i tried "pa", and "za" in both investigator and institution and got the same very surprising results for both. are you sure the back end is returning what you think it should? if it is, i don't think i could guess the difference between right and wrong behavior in this test page.

Comment: What results did you get? In investigator there are 2 records. In institutions, there is a list of about 180 places or so... 
The data coming back is all correct (in my side anyway, what data did you see). The problem I am having is it is not filtering the data at all. It is bringing back ALL the results, regardless of what you type in. Is this the bug you saw, or did you experience something else?

Comment: fsb; if you post your response as an answer, i will accept it for the reputation. I am going with the other autocomplete library, which worked like a breeze, and didn't require a json serialization layer on top of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was completed via fsb's suggestion to use the JZ library in the comments:

> i haven't used jQ-UI. i didn't know the autocomplete was out yet. i use JZ's jquery-autocomplete plugin. but i tried out your test page. i tried "pa", and "za" in both investigator and institution and got the same very surprising results for both. are you sure the back end is returning what you think it should? if it is, i don't think i could guess the difference between right and wrong behavior in this test page.

Answer (score 0):

That jQueryUI function seems to be still in development..

Anyway, in the page you linked it says:

**Dependencies:**

**UI Core**

**UI Widget**

I don't know if this is the real problem, but you're not loading the UI Widget

Comment: Hmmm... I wasn't seeing that in FF3.6 or IE8. I was receiving back actual data, just not filtered. Actually, that may be because I was switching the code to fsb's suggested auto complete library.